# doubt about definition of holomorphic polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, several-complex-variables

In a topic of several complex variable theory (in particular functions on $\mathbb{C}^2$), I came across a term homogeneous holomorphoic polynomial. By the word, I think it is a polynomial in complex variable which is analytic and all of whose terms have same degree. Am I guessing it right? Or maybe can anyone give me the exact definition or reference where I can study these type of polynomials.

Comment: Surely, you are guessing it right. In other words, $f(z)=f(z_1,z_2)=az_1^2+bz_1z_2+z_2^2$. There is no other sensible interpretation.